# fabric js - intermittent loading failure with loadFromJSON

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a fairly simple web app using fabric js to create and edit image layouts. Everything largely seems to work fine, except that sometimes the canvas sometimes doesn't render properly. I've tried to eliminate everything I can, and it seems to be the loadFromJSON method (or, I've tried fabric.util.enlivenObjects, but same problem).

The strangest thing is that it only seems to fail about 30% of the time, wherein I just get empty canvas. Refresh the page, and it might work, might not. There are no console errors at all. The JSON data for the fabric objects is coming from the database, but it's static, and is written into the page directly. It loads images from the server, but they are small, and this is on my local machine, so shouldn't be much 'lag'.

The function that attempts this is as follows:

```
function loadCanvasFromSchema(index) {
    log('loadCanvasFromSchema, index: ' + index)

    let frame = schema.frames[index]
    var c = canvases[index]


    c = new fabric.StaticCanvas('frame' + index, {
      width: frame.width,
      height: frame.height,
      backgroundColor: frame.background
    })

    //c.setDimensions({width: '100%', height: '100%'}, {cssOnly: true})
    //log(c)
    // c.loadFromJSON(frame.fabric, c.renderAll.bind(c))
    fabric.util.enlivenObjects(frame.fabric.objects, function(objects) {
        c.add(...objects);
    })
    c.renderAll()
}
```

There are multiple canvases on page, called like this (but same problem if forced to just load one):

```
function loadAllFromSchema(){
    log('loadAllFromSchema')
    schema.frames.forEach(function(frame, index){
        loadCanvasFromSchema(index)
    })
    // loadCanvasFromSchema(0)
    return true
}
```

At the moment (for testing this), the json is being written into the page from Laravel:

```
<script>
    var canvases = []
    var schema = @json($template->schema)
</script>
```

There is an AlpineJS component which fires all this as follows (but again, I can bypass this and get same problem):

```
init: function(){
            log('alpine init')
            //checkSchema()
            addImagePrefixes()

            this.$nextTick(() => {
                loadAllFromSchema()
            })

        }
```

I'm sure it's something silly, but I'm a bit lost. Much appreciated if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you include the snippet of code that you are fetching the JSON and calling the loadCanvasFromSchema function?

Comment: I don't know Laravel and PHP. Are you sure the schema variable is loaded before the loadCanvasFromSchema function is invoked?

From the behavior it smells like a synchronous and asynchronous code problem. The JSON fetch has not yet occurred at the time the loadCanvasFromSchema function is invoked. When the canvas happens to be blank, if you put a console.log(frame) inside that function, is the data there?

Comment: yes, there's always data there, and it always seems to be okay. Oddly, I can get it to perform better if I use loadFromJSON() but surround it in a 500ms setTimeout ... which further points to some async problem (as you suggest). But this is getting a bit beyond me now; there are never any console errors. The JSON is written into the page by PHP, so there's no async prob there.